# Android Google Map not loading in activity small layout

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-activity, android-mapview

In my application i'm using map view in activity at bottom side.but map doesn't load properly.after clicking on map 2-3 time its shows clear map.& when same map if load in full view it's loading clearly.
What is the solution for this?

screen shot is-

[image]

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

java code-

```
try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) )
        {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:

            mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
            if(mapView!=null)
            {
                map = mapView.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationPosition, 10);
                map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING: 

            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED: 

            break;
        default: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(locationPosition).zoom(10).bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(70)    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();    // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(locationPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_marker)));
```

Comment: What do you mean _map doesn't load properly_?

Comment: after opening activity it shows square box on mapview.it load map after tapping 2-3 time on map

Comment: post your all code ppplzz

Comment: or you can  resume `mapview` on `mMapView.onResume();` and `pause` it on `mMapView.onPause();`

Comment: i'm not getting you.i'm using this in activity

Comment: you need to Resume a Map onResume() to resume your activity or fragement and Pause a Map using onPause() to Pause your activity or fragement

Comment: it's not answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem(I insisted working with the MapView even though it is deprecated at this point).
Here it is my issue and also my answer: [Android Map loading very slow/not loading at all in started activity until clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908988/android-map-loading-very-slow-not-loading-at-all-in-started-activity-until-click)

You need to implement the following methods:
OnResume(); OnPause(); onDestroy(); onLowMemory();